# redirect from devise registration to profile show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3 i am using devise registration... after clicking on apply(submit) button my path should be redirected to profile show page.. how can i achieve this.

can you guide me what i should add in routes file.
here is my routes

```
 devise_for :users do 
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  get '/users/select_type' => 'devise/registrations#select_type'
 end
```

Comment: Do you want to view the individual profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `redirect_to profile_show_path` to redirect. The path name will depend on your `rake routes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the individual profiles in profile_show view. Then you can redirect the profile_show action using this code. 
 `redirect_to :action => :profile_show, :id => @id` 
Then respective profile_show view will be display.